# Clicking on Slideshow works, but the auto run still runs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Essentially, my website's next arrow for the slideshow is working, but when you click on it, the image moves on and the timer still continues instead of stopping. If you keep clicking the next button, it skips the second image and then after stopping, it continues on very quickly in switching images. It is a peculiar bug and here it is in action: https://codepen.io/kush2610/pen/bGNYBPe

HTML CODE

```
  <section class="pictures">
        <h2 >Product Portfolio</h2 >
        <!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494253109108-2e30c049369b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3900&q=80" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485550409059-9afb054cada4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2598&q=80" style="width:100%">
      </div>




    <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>

  <!-- The dots/circles -->
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>

  </div>


    </section>
```

Sorry if this sounds really strange what I am describing but it is such a strange bug I honestly do not know what else to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the same name for both showSlides functions. [Overloading functions is not an option in JavaScript.](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/overloading-functions-javascript/)

```js
/* The SlideShow */
var slideIndex = 0;

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

function showNextSlide() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showNextSlide, 7000); // Change image every 7 seconds
}
showNextSlide();
```

```css
.pictures {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  ;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Hide the images by default */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Slideshow of the area
    ================================================== -->
<section class="pictures">
  <h2>Product Portfolio</h2>
  <!-- Slideshow container -->
  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494253109108-2e30c049369b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3900&q=80" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485550409059-9afb054cada4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2598&q=80" style="width:100%">
    </div>




    <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <br>

  <!-- The dots/circles -->
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>

  </div>


</section>
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info and fixing this! I am but a mere noob at this and this really helps out ty! Interesting that overloading isnt in javascript but in java (I know that they arent related but still lol).

Comment: No problem! If this is the answer you were looking for, please mark it with an upvote and an accepted checkmark so others know you are satisfied with it. It'll give me some points as well. Thanks!

Comment: I got one more question if u do not mind. Basically, how would I ensure this slideshow does not keep changing size. I tried other options online but they didnt work

Comment: You can adjust all the image files you're referring to and change them to have the same width to height ratio, or you can set them as background images of a div with background-size:cover; instead

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `showSlides()` function is setting a timeout which advances the slides. When you click your next button, another function is called, `plusSlides()`, which in turn calls `showSlides()` again. Thus, starting another timeout. The more you click the next button, the more timeouts you'll have running, and the more frequently you'll see your slides advance.

I don't have time to write the code right now, but I'd suggest killing any existing timeouts when you click the next button so you only have one running at a time.

Comment: Sorry I am a noob when it comes to this but what do you mean by killing existing time outs? Does that mean redoing the plus slides in a new way? Also no need to write code but if it is a quick reply that you could answer, please do. If not, no need.